# Pass informations between separate consoles and windows applications

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, console-application, ipc

I have two separate programs, one is a console application, and the other one is a windows application.

**My windows application:**

- Has a graphic interface, buttons, and others functions.
- One of the buttons, named "research": when I click on it, I launch the console application with this line of code:

  ```
  string strResult = ProcessHelper.LaunchProcessWaitForPipedResult("MyExecFile.exe", strArguments, 10 * 60 * 1000, true);   // 10 mins max
  ```

**My console Application:**

- do a query on all existing files in a directory.

**My problem:**

I want to create a progress-bar on the windows application to show the progress of the console application. The problem is I don't know how to pass this information between the two processes. The only restriction is to not use a database or file.

Comment: Do you have the source code of the console? Because as I recall the console will return the absolute result at the end... (unless you could "yield" results)

Comment: There are lots of IPC (inter-process communication) options (eg. windows messages, mailslots, nameed pipe, shared memory TCP/IP socket, …). To help narrow things down: will the two applications always be run in the same login session? (Or will more sophisticated access control be needed?)

Comment: Consider using Namepd pipes to share memory between two apps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb546085%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Richard : The both application always run on the same login session, and in the same emplacement (Same folder)

Comment: On further thought: why do you have two separate programs? Performing the processing in a [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) (or other concurrency approach) in the GUI application would make things much [easier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke.aspx).

Comment: The console application use by anothers program too, that why we keep it like a console, for multi using

Comment: That does not seem to me to be a good reason for keeping it as a console application: much better to be an assembly (class library) that can be referenced by other programs. Expose an `event` so the caller can get progress updates. (Managing separate processes starts not terribly hard, but can rapidly get difficult as you add sophistication: such as ever more communication to and from the parent process.)

Comment: Yes i am totaly agree with you Richard, but this "exe" file is used by different softwares too, Matlab, Javascript, C++,... and you can run it us a command Dos too, that why we keep it like a console

Comment: @Joe what Richard means is that you should be able to split out the Console app part of the program from the library part. Then just reference the library part in your UI program. Its kind of the entire point of dlls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two processes in the same user session, and wanting to avoid any communication outside that session I would look at three options:

#### 1. Using named pipes.

The parent process creates a named pipe using a random name (and confirms that name is not in use by opening it). It passes that name to the child process. A simple protocol is used that allows the child to send updates.

There are a number of challenges to overcome:

- Getting the logic to ensure the name is unique right (named pipe names are global).
- Ensuring no other process can connect (the default named pipe ACL limits connections to the session: this *might* be enough).
- Handling the case where a different parent process does not support progress updates.
- Handling the child or parent crashing.
- Avoiding getting too clever with the communication protocol, but allowing room for growth (what happens when more than a simple progress bar is wanted?)

#### 2. Using Shared Memory

In this case names of objects are, by default, local to the session. By default this is more secure.

The parent process creates a sufficiently large amount of shared memory (for a simple progress update: not much), a mutex and an event.

The parent process then, concurrently with the GUI waits for the event to be signalled, when it is it enters the mutex and reads the content of shared memory. It then unsets the event and leaves the mutex.

Meanwhile to send an update the child enters the mutex, updates and memory and sets the event before leaving the mutex.

The challenges here include:

- Defining the layout of the shared memory. Without a shared assembly this is likely to be error prone.
- Avoiding others using the shared memory and synchronisation objects. .NET makes things harder here: in Win32 I would make the handles inheritable thus not needing to name the objects (except for debugging) and pass to the child directly.
- Getting the sequencing of shared memory, mutex and event correct is critical. Memory corruption and more subtle bugs await any errors.
- It is harder to do variable length data with shared memory, not an issue for a simple progress count but customers always want more.

#### Summary

I would probably look at named pipes in the first place (or perhaps custom WMI types if I wanted greater flexibility). ***BUT*** I would do that only after trying everything to avoid needing multiple processes in the first place. A shared library plus console wrapper for others, while I use the library directly would be a far easier option.

Comment: Whatever happened to using a library...like WCF? For a simple progressbar, the perf of a high level library like WCF should cause very few problems. But if perf is an issue. IPC shouldn't have been used.

Comment: @Aron WCF could be made to work, but (1) anyone would be able to communicate with the server, and (2) WCF is very much client-server RPC pattern but this scenario is one side doing fire and forget of informational, non-critical data. Short version: it could work, but it isn't IMHO the right style of IPC.

Comment: all of your criticisms are specific to certain types of WCF bindings. Using named pipe binding should solve the issue.

Comment: @Aron quite possibly – I don't claim to be up to date with WCF, I've tried to avoid it and WS-* because most of the benefits are irrelevant in most scenarios. But note my 1st comment on the Q: there are many IPC options that could be made to work, but KISS should always apply. In the end any IPC for this is a poor choice (see the last sentence of this answer).

Comment: I definitely agree with the last point. IPC is completely pointless and harmful here. But fyi, named pipe was one of the original bindings shipped with WCF. People often forget that along with MSMQ binding and concentrate on BasicHttp and WS-*.